# MySQL - GROUP_CONCAT on multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have table and query like this:
[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aeb75f/21)

```
SELECT P.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(`trait_name` SEPARATOR ', ') AS traits,
       GROUP_CONCAT(`filter_name` SEPARATOR ', ') AS filters
FROM `products` P 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `personality_traits` 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `product_to_traits` 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `filters` 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `product_to_filters` 
GROUP BY `product_name`
```

I want to select all products and display all traits and filters to which a given product belongs (traits and filters are in separate tables)
it is almost working, result is correct but multiplied. My solution works perfectly fine if I use one GROUP_CONCAT on one table, when I add another table the results are multiplied.

insted of:

```
    +------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
    | product_id | product_name | traits        | filters         |
    +------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
    | 1          | product1     | trait1,trait2 | filter5         |
    | 2          | product2     | trait2,trait3 | filter4,filter2 |
    | 3          | product3     | trait3,trait5 | filter3         |
    | 4          | product4     | trait5,trait1 | filter2         |
    | 5          | product5     | trait1        | filter1         |
    +------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

I get:

```
    +------------+--------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+
    | product_id | product_name | traits                         | filters                            |
    +------------+--------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+
    | 1          | product1     | trait1,trait2                  | filter5,filter5                    |
    | 2          | product2     | trait2, trait2, trait3, trait3 | filter2, filter4, filter2, filter4 |
    | 3          | product3     | trait3,trait5                  | filter3,filter3                    |
    | 4          | product4     | trait5,trait1                  | filter2,filter2                    |
    | 5          | product5     | trait1                         | filter1                            |
    +------------+--------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

thanks!

Comment: Can I suggeest you never use NATURAL JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `trait_name` ORDER BY product_id SEPARATOR ',') AS traits,
       GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `filter_name` ORDER BY product_id SEPARATOR ',') AS filters
FROM `products` P 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `personality_traits` 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `product_to_traits` 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `filters` 
NATURAL JOIN 
       `product_to_filters` 
GROUP BY `product_name`
```